# Datastream - the costs of root partitioned table from PostgreSQL to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-datastream

I have a very large partitioned table in PostgreSQL. It is replicated to BigQuery using Google Datastream as separate partitioned tables (as described in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/work-with-postgresql-partitioned-tables)). Right now I have a separate table in BigQuery for each partition of the PostgreSQL table.

```
my_table_name_2022_01
my_table_name_2022_02
my_table_name_2022_03
...
```

I want to switch the configuration to a single root table.
I am concerned that it may increase the costs of stream table updates in BigQuery.

If I configure a stream with a single root table, will Datastream occasionally scan all BigQuery table partitions during streaming? I am interested in the case when there will be only INSERT and UPDATE operations for the Postgres table. But the case including DELETE, TRUNCATE operations is also interesting.